# script cURl API: message":"Invalid signature"

Tags: api, rest, shell, curl, ovh

I'm trying to use OVH API to update DNS zone entries.
I'm using shell script with cURL command but I get this error :

```
{"message":"Invalid signature","httpCode":"400 Bad Request","errorCode":"INVALID_SIGNATURE"}
```

**Here is the script :**

```
OVH_CONSUMER_KEY="XXXXX"
OVH_APP_KEY="XXXXX"
OVH_APP_SECRET="XXXXX"
HTTP_METHOD="POST"
HTTP_QUERY="https://api.ovh.com/1.0/domain/zone/domaine.fr/record"
HTTP_BODY=""
TIME=$(curl -s https://api.ovh.com/1.0/auth/time)
CLEAR_SIGN="$OVH_APP_SECRET+$OVH_CONSUMER_KEY+$HTTP_METHOD+$HTTP_QUERY+$HTTP_BODY+$TIME"
SIG='$1$'$(echo -n $CLEAR_SIGN | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed -e 's/^.* //')

curl -X $HTTP_METHOD \
$HTTP_QUERY \
-H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8" \
-H "X-Ovh-Application:$OVH_APP_KEY" \
-H "X-Ovh-Timestamp:$TIME" \
-H "X-Ovh-Signature:$SIG" \
-H "X-Ovh-Consumer:$OVH_CONSUMER_KEY" \
-d '{"fieldType":"TXT", "subDomain":"", "target":"VX=SPF"}'
```

**But with this script works fine :**

```
OVH_CONSUMER_KEY="XXXXX"
OVH_APP_KEY="XXXXX"
OVH_APP_SECRET="XXXXX"
HTTP_METHOD="GET"
HTTP_QUERY="https://api.ovh.com/1.0/domain"
HTTP_BODY=""
TIME=$(curl -s https://api.ovh.com/1.0/auth/time)
CLEAR_SIGN="$OVH_APP_SECRET+$OVH_CONSUMER_KEY+$HTTP_METHOD+$HTTP_QUERY+$HTTP_BODY+$TIME"
SIG='$1$'$(echo -n $CLEAR_SIGN | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed -e 's/^.* //')

curl -X $HTTP_METHOD \
$HTTP_QUERY \
-H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8" \
-H "X-Ovh-Application:$OVH_APP_KEY" \
-H "X-Ovh-Timestamp:$TIME" \
-H "X-Ovh-Signature:$SIG" \
-H "X-Ovh-Consumer:$OVH_CONSUMER_KEY"
```

The differences between these 2 scripts are :

- HTTP_METHOD
- HTTP_QUERY
- DATA

Do you have an idea why?

Thanks
L.

Comment: nobody has an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found below:

```
OVH_CONSUMER_KEY="XXXXX"
OVH_APP_KEY="XXXXX"
OVH_APP_SECRET="XXXXX"
HTTP_METHOD="POST"
HTTP_QUERY="https://api.ovh.com/1.0/domain/zone/domaine.fr/record"
txt_type="TXT"
txt_field=""
txt_value='"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"'
HTTP_BODY="{"fieldType":"$txt_type","subDomain":"$txt_field","target":"$txt_value"}"
TIME=$(curl -s https://api.ovh.com/1.0/auth/time)
CLEAR_SIGN=$OVH_APP_SECRET"+"$OVH_CONSUMER_KEY"+"$HTTP_METHOD"+"$HTTP_QUERY"+"$HTTP_BODY"+"$TIME
SIG='$1$'$(echo -n $CLEAR_SIGN | openssl dgst -sha1 -hex | cut -f 2 -d ' ' )

curl -X $HTTP_METHOD \
$HTTP_QUERY \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Ovh-Application: $OVH_APP_KEY" \
-H "X-Ovh-Timestamp: $TIME" \
-H "X-Ovh-Signature: $SIG" \
-H "X-Ovh-Consumer: $OVH_CONSUMER_KEY" \
--data "$HTTP_BODY"
```